# .htaccess redirect to ssl with laravel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I'm trying to use .htaccess to redirect to ssl on login url in laravel.

Login url looks like: four.number.for.ip/auth/login

If I use

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} login
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME} [R=301,L]
```

It doesnt work. I have tried with

```
%{HTTPS} !=on
```

and it works.
And also %{SERVER_NAME} returns ip/auth/login (i'm sure for that, as https!=on works)

I can't see why this won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you. Let me know how it turns out.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/auth/login [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Edit to give full rules. It should look something like this.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/auth/login [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as in laravel, %{REQUEST_URI} is just "index.php", but %{HTTP_HOST} is ip/auth/login...
It should work with SERVER_NAME contains login, but I cant seem to figure out how to do that

Comment: Post your entire htaccess so I don't have to guess what you have.

Comment: Also this should go at the top of your htaccess file.

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} login
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME} [R,L]

Comment: I meant in the question. But my rules above larvels not after.

Comment: I have tried and it doesnt work...Because in my case request_uri is not whole uri but just index.php...

Comment: If you are entering `http://111.111.111.111/auth/login` then REQUEST_URI is `/auth/login`, if it's not you're doing something wrong. Where are you getting index.php in that URL?

Comment: Laravel is irrelevant. You are using the pretty URL code for it. It just passes everything that's not a real file or directory to PHP so that index.php can be removed from the URL. But if you want to redirect to https first before letting it do that, you put that rule first. I updated to include full code.

Comment: Guess I was making some mistake.. it works now.. thanks for help

Comment: It will as long as you are accessing `/auth/login` otherwise the rest of the site will not without changing the rule. Also make sure to mark the answer accepted since you go it working there.